# Disable cell in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, cell

I want to disable some cells in datagrid programatically so user can't change their value and I want to get this cell depending on row and column index ?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the BeginnigEdit event of your DataGrid. Set e.cancel to true to avoid editing.
If your DataGrid is bound to a DataTable, setting some columns of this datatable to readonly might be of some help.
note that in the events args of BeginningEdit you have access to col/row with e.Column and e.Row.